# Does Process inherit dynamic loaded so

Tags: linux, fork

I am writing a simple application in C witch needs to run as a daemon.

I am demonizing the process by forking it and closing stderr,stdout,stdin. My question is? Does the forked process inherits the dynamic loaded libraries from the parent process or do I need to load them again?

If it inherits them the modules will be loaded at the same virtual address as they are in the parent process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, after a fork the new child process will have a copy-on-write clone of the parent's memory space, which includes any shared libraries which may have been loaded and initialized.  At the function call level, anything you could have done in the parent you can do legally in the child.